# How do I show a <ctrl>+<alt>+<del> as a single key?

Tags: support, markdown

I can make keys appear highlighted, even suggest combos <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>del</kbd>, but it shows them as separate keys.

But I want to show that they should be struck together

Comment: I *really* loath to say this because I might be *horribly* wrong and I often comment to others that they shouldn't do this... Have you considered asking a good question over on [user experience.se](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) about the particulars of the message you are trying to convey, what you have tried, why you don't like what you've done so far?

Answer (score 15):

Like <kbd>ctrl+alt+del</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl-alt-del</kbd>?

Don't know why you'd want to do that, having separate keys looks better and makes more sense to me, but just include them in a single `<kbd>` tag (like `<kbd>ctrl+alt+del</kbd>`) if that's what you want.

Or just do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> instead.

Comment: Yes - the extra kbd tag is what I wanted, but was looking more for this `<kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>del</kbd></kbd>`

Comment: @jalanb why? That looks horrible!

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Not sure about OP’s use case, and SE’s `kbd` styling is one thing, but HTML5 explicitly allows this markup. See also on SE Meta: [Can we use 'kbd' according to its definition in HTML5?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215133/193139)

Comment: @unor I'm not saying it doesn't work, I'm saying it **doesn't look good**; try it for yourself in the answer box below and look at the preview! Just because you can, doesn't mean you should - see e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1974/248731

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Yeah, that’s what I meant with "styling is one thing" (however, I’ve no problem with the current styling for nested `kbd` and have used it in various answers); it was meant as an answer to your "why?".